# How to get starting position character value of a text selected in a paragraph with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, textselection

I want to retrieve the starting position of selected text in paragraph.

For example if the paragraph text is "This is a paragraph." and I select "paragraph" with my cursor, the computed property value should be 10.

I tried the strategy explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48149119/10373864. Here is the code:

```
<p ref="paragraph">This is a paragraph.</p>

computed: {
  start: function () { 
    return this.$refs.paragraph.selectionStart
  }
}
```

However, the value of `start` is `undefined`. It seems the method above only works with `textarea`. I cannot use `textarea`. How can I make it work with a paragraph?

Comment: What about these situations: 1) selection starts in paragraph, but ends outside; 2) selection starts outside of paragraph, but ends inside; 3) selection start and ends outside of paragraph, but includes it?