# how to get cursor position of a div element in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can only get the cursor position of input and textarea elements, but how do I do this with div elements that contain contenteditable = "true"?

```js
getCursor() {
      const text = this.$refs.test;
      const value = text.selectionStart;
      console.log(value); // result is undefined
    }
```

```html
<div
  ref="test"
  contenteditable="true"
  :v-html="inputIntegrationHMTL"
  @input="getCursor($event)"
 > </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selectionStart and selectionEnd in contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288700/selectionstart-and-selectionend-in-contenteditable-element)

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```js
getCursor(event) {
      console.log(event); // you can read pos here
}
```

```html
<div
  ref="test"
  contenteditable="true"
  :v-html="inputIntegrationHMTL"
  @mouseover="getCursor($event)"
 > </div>
```

Comment: I need to get the cursor position inside the div text.

Comment: look like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145727/insert-character-at-cursor-position-in-vue-js